# PHP | Gathering the <title> from within the <head> into a variable for use elsewhere

Tags: php

Is there a way to grab the contents of the title tag using PHP, to be used as a variable elsewhere? Or am I only able to change what the title contains?

Comment: You would get far better results doing this in PHP as it'll then be part of the HTML that's sent to the client. Doing it in JS means that there's a delay between the HTML being downloaded, the DOM becoming ready and your JS executing, and that's causing the problem. There's no real way around it.

Comment: Yeah thanks for confirming - do you happen to have an idea of a good way to do this in PHP? Anything you can chip in would be brilliant. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I can't really help as I'm not a PHP dev but it appears you simply need to convert your JS `if` statement to PHP logic, retrieving the `title` value on the server first

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant to store your site's title like this,

```
define('SITE_TITLE', 'My Website');
```

Then use this constant in your PHP file so that when it renders you can add site title to the meta description tag,

`<meta name=\"description\" content=\""<?= SITE_TITLE ?>" - Helping create a better description\"/>`

Comment: Is there a way to adjust this so it dynamically pulls the definition of the site title from the <head>'s <title> tag for each page - if I'm right - this will just create the same description for each page. - @RopAliMunshi

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_title() function for display or retrieve page title for all areas of site.